# How do you suppress the --show-name (filename) option when git blame?

Tags: git

```
-f, --show-name
       Show the filename in the original commit. By default the filename is shown if there is any line that came from a file with a different name, due to rename detection.
```

But `--show-name=off` does not work.

```
error: option `show-name' takes no value
usage: git blame [<options>] [<rev-opts>] [<rev>] [--] <file>
```

How could I hide the verbose filenames from output?

Comment: Could you accept an answer below? To be grateful to people who answered.

Comment: @m-ric Yeah. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Matt McHenry says, `git annotate` doesn't show the filenames.

The trick is that `git blame` takes a `-c` flag that forces the output to conform to the annotate sub-command, which results in no filenames.

Answer (score 13):

This option was introduced in [commit eb93b724](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb93b7240665e35ecc0ed72098e1a5b3352bdc17) (git 1.4.4, Oct. 2006)

> The new option makes the command's native output format show the filename even when there were no renames in its history, to make it simpler for Porcelains to parse its output.

That means:

- not using this option is the way to have it "off"
- when there is rename in history, the filename is *always* shown.

As mentioned in [Edouard Poor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367459/edouard-poor)'s answer, you can use [`git blame -c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame), which  forces the same output mode as [`git-annotate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate).

Comment: Since this answer is marked as correct, consider adding the `-c` = `git annotate` answer from @edouard-poor .

Answer (score 6):

`git annotate` does not include this information in its output.  (It silently ignores the `--show-name` option if you try to activate it.)